# What is the coral-like structure in my nasal cavity?

Tags: nose, tongue

Through rigorous training and deep meditation (AKA prolonged bouts of boredom) I have acquired the ability to maneuver my tongue into my nasal cavity. I can feel the back of my nostrils, and above them, a weird slatted mass. After seeing some rough anatomy sketches on the internet I think is something to do with smell.

What is that coral shaped region? Can I damage it by poking it with my tongue?

By "coral" I mean this stuff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_coral

Comment: Color me skeptical that you can maneuver your tongue into your nasal cavity, but even if you really can, your question is very unclear. What is a `slatted mass`? And what does `coral shaped` mean? Coral comes in many shapes.

Comment: Obviously its hard to explain; I can't _see_ it, only feel it. I imagine it looking like brain-shaped coral. I will try to get a picture of the coral that I mean.

Comment: I have been able to easily stick my tongue in my nasal cavity my whole life due to having a pretty long tongue, everything in there is squishy and fleshy, nothing hard or coral like...

Comment: Thanks for answering a long-standing question for me as well. I have been able to do this for most of my life and have often wondered about that same structure. My frenulum is very stretchy, allowing me to put my tongue above my soft palate, and into my nasal cavity, for any non-believers.

Answer (score 3):

The structure you are searching for is called [nasal conchae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasal_concha).
They are bone lamellae coated with  mucosal tissue and their main purpuse is the augmentation of the surface of the nasal cavity, with the task To clean, warm and moisturize the inhaled air.
It's unlikely that you will be able to damage it  with your toungue.

[image]

[image: Ref CC BY-SA 3.0]

Comment: Yes, to add. If you view a coronal ct or mri, you can visually see the coral shapes as well. Very pretty and well formed on a scan. It’s unique and hard to miss.